# Is there a list of possible values for SYSTEM_HANDLE_ENTRY.ObjectType?

Tags: winapi, pinvoke

I am writing a program that lists open file handles.  I am actually getting too many results.  My list includes stuff like virus scanners.  I am getting a bunch with object type 43 that don't seem like what I want.  Is there a list of these values anywhere?

Comment: These are not documented by MSFT. Your options are to call Nt/ZwQueryObject() for type information or to trust the assumptions of someone else about the enumeration - E.g. look at the Process Hacker project source code.

Answer (score 4):

You can call `NtQueryObject` with specifying `ObjectTypesInformation` information class. That gives you information about all object types currently registered in the system. Use the `SYSTEM_HANDLE_ENTRY.ObjectType` as an index into the returned array in order to get information about the corresponding object type. Alternatively, you can use `NtQueryObject` with `ObjectTypeInformation` to obtain type information about a given object (specified by its handle).

This code should retrieve information about all type objects.

```
typedef enum _OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS {
  ObjectBasicInformation,
  ObjectNameInformation,
  ObjectTypeInformation,
  ObjectTypesInformation,
  ObjectHandleFlagInformation,
  ObjectSessionInformation,
} OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS;

typedef struct _OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION {
  UNICODE_STRING TypeName;
  ULONG TotalNumberOfObjects;
  ULONG TotalNumberOfHandles;
  ULONG TotalPagedPoolUsage;
  ULONG TotalNonPagedPoolUsage;
  ULONG TotalNamePoolUsage;
  ULONG TotalHandleTableUsage;
  ULONG HighWaterNumberOfObjects;
  ULONG HighWaterNumberOfHandles;
  ULONG HighWaterPagedPoolUsage;
  ULONG HighWaterNonPagedPoolUsage;
  ULONG HighWaterNamePoolUsage;
  ULONG HighWaterHandleTableUsage;
  ULONG InvalidAttributes;
  GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;
  ULONG ValidAccessMask;
  BOOLEAN SecurityRequired;
  BOOLEAN MaintainHandleCount;
  ULONG PoolType;
  ULONG DefaultPagedPoolCharge;
  ULONG DefaultNonPagedPoolCharge;
} OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION, *POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _OBJECT_TYPES_INFORMATION {
  LONG NumberOfTypes;
// OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION TypeInformation [1];
} OBJECT_TYPES_INFORMATION, *POBJECT_TYPES_INFORMATION;

NTSTATUS QueryObjectTypesInfo(POBJECT_TYPES_INFORMATION *TypesInfo)
{
  ULONG StartBufferLength = 28;
  ULONG BufferLength = 0;
  NTSTATUS status = 0xC0000001;

  status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
  *TypesInfo = (POBJECT_TYPES_INFORMATION)malloc(StartBufferLength);
  if (*TypesInfo != NULL) {
    status = NtQueryObject(NULL, ObjectTypesInformation, TypesInfo, StartBufferLength, &BufferLength);
    if (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) {
      *TypesInfo = NULL;
      while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) {
        if (*TypesInfo != NULL)
          free(*TypesInfo);

        *TypesInfo = (POBJECT_TYPES_INFORMATION)malloc(BufferLength);
        if (*TypesInfo != NULL)
          status = NtQueryObject(NULL, ObjectTypesInformation, *TypesInfo, BufferLength, &BufferLength);
        else status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
      }

      if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        if (*TypesInfo != NULL) {
          free(*TypesInfo);
          *TypesInfo = NULL;
        }
      }
    }
  } else status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

  return status;
}
```

As stated in the comment(s) above, this stuff is quite undocumented. However, the above code (with slight modifications.. e.g. you need to get address of the `NtQueryObject` routine and define some `NTSTATUS` contants) works for me on 64-bit Windows 8.1.

For a complete code (that is quite old and commented in Czech), download this project from my (Czech) website:
https://jadro-windows.cz/download/ntqueryobject.zip

Use `qo.exe --list-types` command to obtain the type information